# Copy-item duplicating some directories in sub directories. (Real head-scratcher)

Tags: powershell, copy-item

When copying a Windows profile, I am successfully copying and excluding the voluminous "AppData" folder. But the side effect is that in the backup folder, sub-folder "Documents" duplicates are showing up.

```
$UserProfPath = "C:\Users\" + $UserID
$UserProfPathAllItems = $UserProfPath + "\*"
$UserBkpPath = $BackupLocation + "\" + $UserID

Copy-Item -Path (Get-Item -Path $UserProfPathAllItems -Exclude ('Appdata')).FullName -Destination            $UserBkpPath -Force -Recurse
```

This works, but it makes redundant "My Music", "My Pictures", and "My Videos" folders in the "Documents" sub-folder (but does not copy files); and that is the only redundant 3 folders it makes!
Where in this logic would this line make these 3 redundant folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are **[*hidden, system-defined junctions*](https://www.svrops.com/svrops/articles/jpoints.htm)** (junctions are akin to symbolic *links* to other directories) that exist **solely for backward compatibility** with pre-Vista versions of Windows.
E.g., the legacy path `$HOME\Documents\My Music` simply redirects to `$HOME\Music`

**Your [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) call includes `-Force`, which includes *hidden* items**, so these system junctions are included in the copy operation and **become regular, non-hidden, empty directories** - this behavior is problematic, for the reasons discussed in the next section.

**Solution options:**

- *Either*: Simply delete the unwanted directories after the fact:

  ```bash
  Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $UserBkpPath\Documents\* -Include 'My Music', 'My Pictures', 'My Videos'
  ```
- *Or*, *assuming that* the directory trees that you want to copy *do not contain directory junctions / directory symlinks that you DO want to copy (as such)*, you can use **`Robocopy.exe`** with its `/XJD` option (add `/SL` if you want to copy *file* symlinks as such):

  ```bash
  robocopy.exe $UserProfPath $UserBkpPath /E /XD AppData /XJD
  ```

  - Using [robocopy.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) has the added advantage of being *faster* than `Copy-Item`.

---

###### Background information:

You can discover these system junctions in a given directory tree as follows:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Attributes Hidden+System+ReparsePoint -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore $UserProfPath
```

- `-ErrorAction Ignore` is needed, because in *Windows PowerShell* [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) tries to *recurse into* these junctions, which fails due to lack of permissions (even when running *elevated*). In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), `Get-ChildItem` no longer does that (but you may still encounter permission-denied errors when running without elevation).
- Target `C:\` to find them on the entire C: drive, though you'll need to run *with elevation* (as administrator) to also see other users' system junctions.

The fact that when such system junctions are copied they turn into regular directories *in principle* is *somewhat* justifiable:

- As demonstrated in [GitHub issue #5240](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5240), **up to at least PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x (current as of this writing), `Copy-Item` currently *invariably* copies a symlink's / NTFS reparse point's *target* rather than the *link itself***.

  - The fact that you currently cannot even choose the latter by *opt-in* is a problem in itself.
- However, there are two **problematic aspects** (in addition to currently *not* being able to request that links be copied *as links*):

  - With `-Recurse`, a *directory* link's target is normally also copied *recursively*.

    - In the case at hand, it is the *lack of permissions* to recurse into *system junctions* that (somewhat *fortunately*, in this particular case) *prevents* this recursive copying.
    - However, arguably this shouldn't fail *silently*, as it currently does.
  - Irrespective of whether the target is a link or not, `Copy-Item` currently *doesn't copy file-system attributes* such as `Hidden`, `ReadOnly`, or `System` for *directories*:

    - See [GitHub issue #20674](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20674).

Answer (score 0):

So the "why" of this is clear, thanks for the clarification!
I chose to take the suggestion above... @mklement0

> Simply delete the unwanted directories after the fact.

Here is my solution to delete these folders "After the fact":

```
$UserBkpDocumentsPath = $UserBkpPath + "\Documents"
$DeleteGarbageDirs = "My Music", "My Pictures", "My Videos"

If (Test-Path -LiteralPath $UserBkpDocumentsPath) {
    ForEach ($Dir in $DeleteGarbageDirs) {
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath (Join-path -Path $UserBkpDocumentsPath -ChildPath $Dir) -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
        }
```

BTW, *this process is replacing Robocopy*, that solution is not available to me. Company standards are forcing rewrite of my established processes into ps1 files.

Comment: robocopy still is the best native tool for large file copies, so replacing it for the sake of it I cannot recommend

Comment: Glad to hear the explanation helped. I've added a simpler way to remove the unwanted directories (a single `Remove-Item` call) to my answer. Given that `Robocopy.exe` _comes with Windows_ and - like any external program - can be called directly from PowerShell: Are you saying you're expressly forbidden from calling it by company policy?